# To add items in list view dynamically

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i have a list view i have to add the items dynamically.I tired but i couldn't do it.pls anyone help me to solve the issue:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnllyrs" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListView ID="lvProcess" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate></asp:ListView></ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

codebehind:

```
dtUserProcess = dsUserProcess.Tables[0];//holds items
 lvProcess.DataSource = dtUserProcess;
                lvProcess.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which field you are displaying in list view.Try this and instead  of "name" give your column

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnllyrs" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:ListView ID="lvProcess" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%# Eval("LayerDescription")%>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: i want to display LayerDescription how to do?